# (React-redux front-end developing) should I use css or add another framework?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-redux

I am working on a web project. I use react-redux for this. I did nearly everything in back-end. But I would like to improve my project's visual side(I mean front-end side). I am currently using bootstrap/reactstrap. Is there a way to manipulate bootstrap? Or should I use css? Any suggestion would be helpfull.

Comment: manipulate bootstrap !! what do you mean by that would you elaborate ??

Answer (score 0):

If you are still starting the UI then I would suggest going for flexbox. You can use Bulma framework which is very good. I f you want to go ahead with bootstrap then you have only to edit the css. You can also make you of scss which makes your life more easier.

Answer (score 0):

These are the best front-end libraries for react applications

- https://materializecss.com/
- https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce

Comment: That's quite subjective and they are not even the most popular, material-ui is

Answer (score 0):

use the styled-components npm package. it will improve your CSS code. and also you can pass the props to the styled-components and etc.

read a document [enter link description here](https://www.styled-components.com/docs)

if you want to animate your page, my suggestion is react-transition-group.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can use css as external file and import in your file . Also inline css support in  react components ,the code like

```
class MyHeader extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <h1 style={{color: "red"}}>Hello Style!</h1>
      <p>Add a little style!</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

There are css styling libraries available

[materializecss](https://materializecss.com/)

[material-ui](https://material-ui.com/)

[semantic-ui](https://semantic-ui.com/)

Answer (score 0):

For the front end, you can use material-ui. Really complete but not easy to use for a new. 
https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#contained-buttons

YOu can also use styled components. It's really easy. 
https://www.styled-components.com/